# Algorithm for skipping or deleting "mirror" data

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I am reading in a file that looks like this:

```
line#        person-pin   reciprocal-person-pin  relationship   reciprocal-relationship
1             2942         3911                   son            mother                     
2             3911         2560                   client         financial advisor
3             3911         1195                   employee       employer
4             3911         1190                   church member  church
5             3911         2942                   mother         son
6             3911         3910                   mother         daughter
7             3911         3912                   mother         daughter
8             3911         5062                   wife           husband
```

As you see in this data, line 5 is a "mirror" of line 1 (same values but flip-flopped). I want to skip one of these rows, not both. Either the first 2942 - 3911 (line 1) can be retained, or 3911 - 2942 (5) can be retained. I'd kind of prefer the "mirror" line 5 to stay but it's not that important.

I tried this algorithm below, but it deletes/skips over **all** the rows - the pair and its mirror - rather than just skipping one of them.

Any thoughts?? I will keep working on this, but I'm stumped and would love some clever ideas.

```
FOR EACH ttRelationshipData:

    FIND FIRST ttRelationshipData2 WHERE ttRelationshipData.person-pin EQ ttRelationshipData2.reciprocal-person-pin
                                     AND ttRelationshipData.reciprocal-person-pin EQ ttRelationshipData2.person-pin NO-LOCK NO-ERROR.

    IF AVAILABLE ttRelationshipData2 THEN NEXT.
    ELSE DO:
        CREATE ttRelationship.
        ASSIGN
            ttRelationship.alpha-pin = ttRelationshipData.constituent-pin
            ttRelationship.alpha-role = ttRelationshipData.constituent-relationship-name
            ttRelationship.bravo-pin =  ttRelationshipData.related-constituent-pin
            ttRelationship.bravo-role = ttRelationshipData.relatedconstituent-rel-name.
    END.
END.
```

The output would look like this:

```
line#        person-pin   reciprocal-person-pin  relationship   reciprocal-relationship
                  
1             3911         2560                   client         financial advisor
2             3911         1195                   employee       employer
3             3911         1190                   church member  church
4             3911         2942                   mother         son
5             3911         3910                   mother         daughter
6             3911         3912                   mother         daughter
7             3911         5062                   wife           husband
```

Comment: To my eyes line 5 is not a duplicate of line 1.

Comment: oh my gosh. Thanks for noticing that. That's a critical error on my part. I corrected it. What I mean, and I believe you understood, is a "duplicate pair". So 2942-3911 is considered a duplicate pair of 3911-2942.

Comment: What is the difference between skipping or deleting a line and deduping it? Isn't that what you want? One relationship entry per "duplicate"? (I look at them more as "mirrors" than "duplicates" but...)

Comment: I like "mirror", that is a more accurate term. They can either be skipped or they can be deleted. Exactly. As you say, one relationship entry per pair and mirrors should be skipped/deleted.

Comment: Your code snippet and your data do not seem to match with regards to field names. A simple can-find first with the reversed keys should be sufficient, but then which record do you want to keep?

Comment: Thanks for the observation that the field names do not match. I changed the field names to match. I'd rather keep the mirrored pair, actually, but either is acceptable.

Comment: Your requirements are confusing. Your post says "but it deletes/skips over all those rows rather than deduping" as if that is a problem in your sample code and yet the question and these comments seem to be asking for code that will do exactly that.

Comment: May I also suggest that you add a working example including sample data at https://abldojo.services.progress.com/ and share that.

Comment: I changed the explanation to hopefully be more clear, and I will add a working sample to abldojo tomorrow. What a cool tool!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test will be true for both rows 1 and 5, so both are skipped, test for the ttRelationShip table instead.

I made some other changes to your code

- NO-LOCK does not apply to temp-tables
- alternate styling to avoid horizontal scrollbars
- after `then next` you don't need the else block
- use labels on next

```
CreateLoop:
FOR EACH ttRelationshipData:

    FIND ttRelationship
        WHERE ttRelationship.alpha-pin = ttRelationshipData.related-constituent-pin
          AND ttRelationship.bravo-pin = ttRelationshipData.constituent-pin
        NO-ERROR.

    IF AVAILABLE ttRelationship THEN NEXT CreateLoop.

    CREATE ttRelationship.
    ASSIGN
        ttRelationship.alpha-pin = ttRelationshipData.constituent-pin
        ttRelationship.alpha-role = ttRelationshipData.constituent-relationship-name
        ttRelationship.bravo-pin =  ttRelationshipData.related-constituent-pin
        ttRelationship.bravo-role = ttRelationshipData.relatedconstituent-rel-name.

END.
```